# How to read on Holding register of MiCOM relay with C# ( ModBus RTU over RS-485 Communication)

Tags: c#, modbus

I've tried PC to MiCOM P127 Relay (master-slave) communication using Modbus RTU protocol in RS-485
I used visual Studio C# to make program to read holding register of device. I want to read from
0080-0081,=> 0089 address [from this manual](https://www.se.com/id/library/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/SE_LOCAL/APS/210469_461E/MiCOM_P12y,_Manual__global_file__P12Y_EN_M_Fa5.pdf)

[image]
[image]

Here is some of code on Visual Studio

```
 public class ModbusRTUProtocol
{
    // Declares variables
    private byte slaveAddress = 1;
    private byte function = 3;// 
    private ushort startAddress = 128;//0080 hex => 128 dec
    private uint _NumberOfPoints = 3;

    private SerialPort serialPort1 = null;
    private List<Register> _Registers = new List<Register>();

    public ModbusRTUProtocol(uint pNumberOfPoints)
    {
        this.NumberOfPoints = pNumberOfPoints;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.NumberOfPoints; i++)
        {
            _Registers.Add(new Register() { Address = (ushort)(startAddress + i) }); // cast type to ushort.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts Modbus RTU Service.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM7", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
            serialPort1.Open();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    {
                        byte[] frame = ReadHoldingRegistersMsg(slaveAddress, startAddress, function, NumberOfPoints);
                        serialPort1.Write(frame, 0, frame.Length);
                        Thread.Sleep(100); // Delay 100ms
                        if (serialPort1.BytesToRead >= 5)
                        {
                            byte[] bufferReceiver = new byte[this.serialPort1.BytesToRead];
                            serialPort1.Read(bufferReceiver, 0, serialPort1.BytesToRead);
                            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();

                            // Process data.
                            byte[] data = new byte[bufferReceiver.Length - 5];
                            Array.Copy(bufferReceiver, 3, data, 0, data.Length);
                            UInt16[] result = Word.ByteToUInt16(data);
                            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                            {
                                Registers[i].Value = result[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(20); // Delay 20ms
                }
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    private byte[] ReadHoldingRegistersMsg(byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, byte function, uint numberOfPoints)
    {
        byte[] frame = new byte[8];
        frame[0] = slaveAddress;                // Slave Address
        frame[1] = function;                    // Function             
        frame[2] = (byte)(startAddress >> 8);   // Starting Address High
        frame[3] = (byte)startAddress;          // Starting Address Low            
        frame[4] = (byte)(numberOfPoints >> 8); // Quantity of Registers High
        frame[5] = (byte)numberOfPoints;        // Quantity of Registers Low
        byte[] crc = this.CalculateCRC(frame);  // Calculate CRC.
        frame[frame.Length - 2] = crc[0];       // Error Check Low
        frame[frame.Length - 1] = crc[1];       // Error Check High
        return frame;
    }

    private byte[] CalculateCRC(byte[] data)
    {
        ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF; // Set the 16-bit register (CRC register) = FFFFH.
        byte CRCHigh = 0xFF, CRCLow = 0xFF;
        char CRCLSB;
        byte[] CRC = new byte[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < (data.Length) - 2; i++)
        {
            CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ data[i]); // 

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                CRCLSB = (char)(CRCFull & 0x0001);
                CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) & 0x7FFF);

                if (CRCLSB == 1)
                    CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ 0xA001);
            }
        }
        CRC[1] = CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
        CRC[0] = CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
        return CRC;
    }

    public uint NumberOfPoints
    {
        get
        {
            return _NumberOfPoints;
        }

        set
        {
            _NumberOfPoints = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Register> Registers
    {
        get
        {
            return _Registers;
        }

        set
        {
            _Registers = value;
        }
    }
}
```

[Source here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZiZ8o0e35fGkHb7zAUrCdd4Q1GrKSSwp/view?usp=sharing)

Value on this app is different to real value on device
[image]

Please help me. How should I edit that code to get the correct data ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the manual you linked:

> F18A Unsigned long integer: numeric data: 0 to (2E32 -1)

So we are dealing with a 32 bit number stored across two registers. This means we need to think about encoding. The [modbus standard](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) says:

> MODBUS uses a ‘big-Endian’ representation for addresses and data items.

so the byte order within a register is set (and this is implemented in your `ReadHoldingRegistersMsg` function). However it does not state how to combine multiple registers so larger numbers can be processed. I had a scan through the manual you provided and cound not see any mention of this but trying the two options points towards a [little-endian](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FAQ.htm#Order) order (meaning the second register is the high part of the number).

Taking the data from your screenshot Register 0080 = 21210 and register 0081 = 5. Assuming  a little endian format that equals (5*65536)+21210=348890 (note: This is easier to visualise in hex hi = 0x05, low = 0x52DA, result = 0x552DA). As the docs state this figure is 10mv we divide by 100,000 to get kv so 3.4889kv (expected 3.5kV).

Checking out the next two; 0082 = 21789; 0083 = 5. (5*65536)+21789=349,469. Converts to 3.49469kV (expected 3.5kV). For completeness UC works out as 3.49007kV (expected 3.5kV).

Now lets look at register 88 - 6.06kv; from the manual format F1 is

> Unsigned integer: numerical data 0 to 65535

So these should be straight voltages:

0088 - 6351 = 6.351kV (expected 6.06)
0089 - 6358 = 6.358kV (expected 6.07)
0090 - 6343 = 6.343kV (expected 6.06)

The above are not exact matches to the values you provided but I suspect that might be down to timing (you will need to perform some testing). Hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for detail explaining . How do you get formula like (5*65536)+21210=348890. ? I just tested sometimes then value at 0088,0089 always is 63xx is not match what I expect

Comment: Re the formula - you could also use ```((uint)hiWord)<<16 + loWord;```; the largest unsigned 16 bit value is 65535 so when combining two values a 1 in the high word = 65536. Re your testing; unfortunately I don't have access to one of these meters so can only help you interpret the [manual](https://www.se.com/ww/resources/sites/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/content/live/FAQS/364000/FA364036/en_US/P12Y_EN_M_Gb5.pdf) which indicates that this should be an unsigned integer.

Comment: sorry to bother you. But Can you take the time to view my C# code and where should I edit to correct it ?. Thank you

Comment: Your current code is mixed between generic modbus (e.g. ```_Registers```) and code for this specific requirement (e.g. ```startAddress = 128```); personally I'd use an modbus library (that would, for example, handle errors better than your code) and just handle the parsing in my code. If you want to stick with what you gave then  you could add a, for example, ```GetUA()``` member function that returns something like ```_Registers[0] << 16 | _Registers[1]``` (another way of doing the conversion). Note that have not used C# for some time so this is a rough suggestion only.